# Do people who sing with lots of power have a smaller vocal range?

Tags: voice

Do people who sing with lots of power have a smaller vocal range? I have heard that if one sings with power, eg like an opera singer, you will get a smakler range. I feel that the more power I use the harder it is to sing higher.
Is there anything ti this?

Comment: What do you mean by "power"? If you try to push a lot of air with your lungs, that will normally have a negative effect on your range and your tone, but that's not the same thing as having power. Powerful vocals come from training and practice and proper use of all the parts of the body involved in singing. You should learn to sing with the least amount of "pushing air" as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This question is confusing me. Who among us thinks Whitney Houston or Mariah Carey or Luciano Pavarotti lacks power or extended range in their voices. There are certainly singers with power, but limited range, but I know of no evidence linking one with the other. With study, voices can be developed, power developed and vocal range increased, but it usually requires work.

Comment: I would point out that old age very often does affect both power and vocal range.

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to define such words as "power"... But if you mean with it, that they can sing stronger, louder tones, I would say definitely that the range isn't affected by the fact with how much 'power' you sing.

If you sing louder, with much pressure, you may be running out of breath sooner, because you use more air when singing that way, but the vocal range itself isn't affected by this.

Just hum quietly and go as high as you can. Now stop and sing the same note with open mouth and 'power'. You could still reach the tone right? You probably just couldn't hold it just as long, because you used way more air that way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my listening experience as well as first-hand singing, I would say there's no correlation between "limited range" and "power".

On the contrary, it's common for some singers to need to appeal to increased air pressure to reach the upper end of their vocal range (think of songs you can remember in which the singer belts a "high" note, which very often is accompanied by a surge in "power").  So if anything, I would answer "no" to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't.  This is a bizarre claim, and if the person who made it has evidence - let's hear it!